# Popover view in iPhone

Tags: iphone, view, scrollview, popover

I add a vertical scroll view on a UIView. then add some " MidRight" buttons from the link below onto the scroll view. https://github.com/lexrus/FPPopover

when I click one of the " MidRight" buttons in the scroll view, a popover " tableview" appears. when I click one row of the table view, and click outside the popover, the popover dismisses.

how to achieve such effect that, when I click one row of the table view, an image could be added to the UIView of the scroll view according to the row's tag.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use [WEPopover](https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover/issues/20)

it's may be helpful for u..

Comment: I have noticed this Demo before, thanks for your prompt reply anyway!

Answer (score 0):

you can get the selectedRaw number from `DemoTableController` class and delegate method `-didSelectRowAtIndexPath` you can get tag or raw number like bellow..

just import the `FPViewController.h` in `DemoTableController.m` file like bellow..

```
#import "FPViewController.h"
```

and then this bellow method call this..

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
       int TagNo = indexPath.row;
       NSLog("\n Row No. : %d",TagNo);
       FPViewController *objFPView= [[ FPViewController alloc]init];
      [objFPView AddImageWithTag:TagNo];
}
```

also create one method in `FPViewController.h` file like bellow

```
-(void)AddImageWithTag:(int)tag;
```

and in `FPViewController.m'

```
-(void)AddImageWithTag:(int)tag{
    NSLog(@"\n\n Tag Number : %d",tag);
}
```

i hope this help you...

Comment: thanks Paras for your prompt reply! Actually I integrated the FPPopover project onto the " Scroller " project downloaded from this: Project Files
Download the Feb 2011 updated project files: iPhone iOS 4.x Projects v1.1.zip (Feb 2011 Release)

Comment: http://teachyourselfiphone.com/?page_id=43    , I changed all "FPViewController" in your suggestions to "ScrollerViewController", and just wanted to test to add an image to the UIView of the Scroller App without related to a number of the row. But failed to add an image to the UIView of the Scroller App.

Comment: '- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   int TagNo = indexPath.row;
   ScrollerViewController *objFPView= [[ ScrollerViewController alloc]init];  UIImage  *image1 =[UIImage imageNamed:@"Checkers.png"];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc ]initWithImage:image1]; 
    

    //[self.view addSubview: imageView];  // this add the image to the tableview itself, instead of UIView of the Scroller project which I wanted to achieve.
   [objFPView addSubview: imageView]; }'

Comment: you get the log and also add image manualy just add image on AddImageWithTag method and i not understand why you change the FPView to ScrollView

Comment: oh dude just try to add like in -(void)AddImageWithTag:(int)tag{
    NSLog(@"\n\n Tag Number : %d",tag);[scrollview addSubview: imageView];
}

Comment: so sorry, Paras, I can't express properly here, would you please leave me your email so that I may send my project to you? that will be clear to you once you see my project. thanks! Sorry for the trouble caused to you. I still can't input my code in proper format here .